# Issues Localizing a Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

This is my first time trying to localize, so bear with me. I've read up on it, but am still dealing with limited experience in the subject.

I've gone through a demo and have it working fine and I feel like I understand what happens behind the scenes. I moved the same concepts into my actual application, and it will not work. I've set the Localizable property to true and created an English and French resource file.

I've confirmed that my application is still pulling from the regular .resx file instead of en-US.resx or the French one.

I've tried setting these before the InitializeComponent call:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

I've even tried to call a few particular ones explicitly:

```
resources.ApplyResources(this, "$this", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

resources gets declared as:

```
System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(myForm));
```

It all still pulls from the .resx file. One difference in this over my test project is that this form inherits from another, but I have made sure to set that form's Localizable property and resource files as well. Any ideas would be appreciated.

EDIT: I've still been working on this. I have a test project that works and my main application that does not. If I copy over the form that works in the the test over to the main, it does not work. If I add a reference to the main app in my test, the form from the main app also does not work even though it is straight copied from the test that works. Any ideas?

EDIT: It seems like the main difference/issue is that the basic project that is working is an executable by itself while my main application is calling an assembly with this localized form in it. Still no idea what is wrong. A lot of the tutorials I am seeing use System.Resources.ResourceManager, but when I change the form to localizable it auto-uses System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager.

EDIT: I can literally say

```
resources.ApplyResources(this, "$this", new CultureInfo("fr-CA"));
```

and it will ignore the $this.Text in the .fr-CA.resx file and use the default .resx file instead. I Don't Understand. And that is just me trying to FORCE it to work. I still need to just set the culture like normal. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you localize a form, it creates a folder per language in the build's output path that holds a resource file projectname.resources.dll.

I have a post build command that puts our .dlls elsewhere. I needed to change the command to also push out the resource files so that they were in the same directory. Once I did this, I was able to get it to work.

Comment: I have the same problem, could you tell me how did you solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the CreateSpecificCulture instead of new CultureInfo() for the threads CurrentCulture.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(languageCode);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(languageCode);
```

As a side note, if your default culture is going to be English then you do not need to create a labels.en-US.rex. You can put that in the labels.resx and that will load up front and be the fallback. Gives you one less file you need to keep in sync.

Comment: That didn't work. I confirmed that Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture gets set to "en-US" after the statement.

Comment: My default will be English and thanks for the tip. I'm just using during testing for now until I can figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: Can you access the global Resources class generated for your resources in your code. i.e. If you have a resource named labels then Resources.labels.lblMyLabelName? This should be the value that you set in the Custom Tool Namespace of the resource file properties panel.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. The resource files and what are inside get created automatically (granted I've looked inside to verify they are correct). None of my resource files have anything set in the Custom Tool Namespace property. Neither does my example project that works.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the relevant line below to the main method in Program.cs (other lines added for context)

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

// THIS LINE - Only need to set UI culture the other one is for currency etc
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");

// Or whatever your form is called.
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

This guarantees you are setting the culture before any InitialiseComponent method calls. 
I've eyeballed this working.

Comment: This didn't work either. Is there any other information I can provide that might help shed light on the situation?

Comment: Yes, actually, can you email me the code or application, I don't mind working through it?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to give you everything, so I tried to strip it down and move it to another project. It worked when I did that, so I've narrowed it down to where the only difference is that I am inheriting from another form. Is there anything special I need to do? I've tried setting this baseForm to also be localized, but that didn't help.

Comment: I'll try that specific scenario. I suspect it some nuanced idiosyncrasy!

Comment: I have 2 forms. Form2 inherits from Form1.  When working with the second form, like the first, I had to ensure that I set the language  (German in my case) in the properties dialog with the form selected in the designer.  Edit the control text on the form ( a label in my case) and then save it.  I could see that an appropriate resource file for my inherited form (not just base form!)was created w. Try recreating these steps.  In summary just check your other resource files for your second form are present and correct.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to test this. I have verified that all of the appropriate resource files were created in my second form and the code in InitializeComponents() is looking at them. i.e. resources.ApplyResources(this, "$this"); For some reason it is refusing to look anywhere but the basic .resx file.

Comment: So just to be clear, I have 3 resx files. a US, French, and the originl .resx. My default language, as well as the one I am manually setting it to, is US. I can't for the life of me get it to pay attention to anything except the original resx.